# Delete statement suddenly taking more time in Oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I had a table `test` that has 25000 rows in Oracle 11g. I had given a `Delete` statement as Follows.

```
delete from test;
```

This query was running more than 5 minutes but still not coming out and am not getting any error messages also. Can someone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Are there triggers defined on the table?  Are there foreign keys that reference `TEST`?  If you are deleting all the rows in the table, is there a reason that you don't `TRUNCATE` the table rather than doing a `DELETE`?  Do you need the `DELETE` to be transactional?

Comment: nope!! No triggers defined on that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
delete from test nologging;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `delete` without a filter, you're better off using `truncate` as turbanoff said. Also in my experience using a `delete from table` within a script of some sort causes the symptoms you are having.